# Может ли js или java сайта отправить https запрос с IP пользователя к другому домену?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

Допустим сайт открыт в окне браузера у пользователя... Может ли сайт каким то образом отправлять при этом HTTPS запросы с IP пользователя на другой домен, например google.com?
js или java способны на это? и запрещаются ли такие вещи антивирусами?

Comment: Ну вообще-то только с IP пользователя и может. Потому что это будет запрос из браузера пользователя, так что других IP у него нет.

Comment: К другому домену -  ключевой момент тут. Когда в окне браузера открыт не тот домен а другой. Например открыто окно сайта site1.ru и некоторые https запросы отправляются на сайт google.com

Comment: А как по вашему работают всякие яндекс и гугл метрики? Таки обращаются к своим доменам

Comment: @Mart, для скриптов на странице может действовать (и обычно действует) ограничение same-origin policy. К скриптам браузерных расширений, эта политика не применяется, *но* в манифесте расширения должны быть указаны permissions для сетевого доступа к этим "другим" доменам (можно запрашивать права на сетевой доступ вообще-куда-угодно, только некоторые юзеры очень настороженно относятся к таким расширениям... и правильно делают).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, JavaScript может отправлять запросы на другой домен. Запросы будут с ip адреса пользователя.

Comment: А Java это язык для серверной части.

Comment: Могут ли быть ограничения у браузера на такие действия? на количество запросов в секунду или нагрузку процессора

Comment: Ограничения конечно могут быть. Но смотрите, запрос например к API Google это же запрос на внешний сайт. Ограничения нужно смотреть по конкретному браузеру. Но точнее это будут ограничения мощности ПК на котором установлен браузер.